# Change default webcam image in genymotion

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator, android-camera, genymotion

I want to change the default dummy webcam image and instead play a video/gif.

Below is the default dummy webcam video/gif - [image]

Is it possible or is there any alternative.

My purpose is that if I open any app I can use that video instead of dummy webcam image

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a workaround, but you can create a fake webcam on your host computer and use that webcam when you select `Physical (real) webcam` as your camera source.

A [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=fake%20webcam) search lists multiple programs that are capable of doing this, for example [Fake Webcam](http://www.fakewebcam.com/) should do the trick.

Comment: great idea, let's try it out

Comment: you CANT do that. Genymotion only recognizes your real webcam, it is shitty

Answer (score 0):

As Paulo Roberto Rosa said Genymotion desktop doesn't support it till now even in new update. Don't waste your time for searching about this.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.